# ReactJs Promise + Ajax Return Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a function which uses jquery to call API and get a result. My API end is programmed to return the number "19" just for testing.

```
export function clientAdd(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.example.com/client/add/",
            headers: {'AUTHORIZATION': `${sessionStorage.jwt}`},
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                let redirectUrl = '/client/' + data
                return redirectUrl';

            },
            error: function(xhr, status, err)  {

                if (xhr.status === 401) {
                    sessionStorage.removeItem('jwt');
                    return '/signin';

                }
                console.log('xhr',xhr.responseText);
                console.log('status',status);
                console.log('err',err);
                return dispatch({type: GET_CLIENT_FAIL, err});
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Then in my component, upon clicking on the submit button, it will call the onSave function as follows

```
  onSave(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    this.props.actions.clientAdd(this.state.credentials).then((result) => {
        return this.setState({redirect: true, newCustomerId: result})

    }).catch((result) => {
        return this.setState({redirect: false, errorMessage: result})
    });
  }
```

Where the **result** is supposed to be the **redirectUrl** or **ErrorMessage**.

However, I'm keep getting the number 19 which is returned by my API.

I read online if I want to use promise in my component, i have to add return infront of $.ajax, if not "then" will be undefined.

Comment: AFAIK, `$.ajax` does not return a Promise.  Maybe you should use something that does?  Or, you will have to wrap a new Promise around the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: i know $.ajax is not a promise, but it returns a value. So what I want is my onSave function to call clientAdd function, and upon receiving the return value, to move on to the next call.

Comment: It seems to return a `jqXHR` object.  The `success` callback returns a value, but that will obviously not be returned from `clientAdd`.  Also, you are wrapping another function: `(dispatch) => `.  You seem to be mixing many concepts, maybe just follow the redux docs: https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Comment: Yes, I was on redux-thunk to async dispatch reducer, then also needed promise to return to the component to move on to next action. Very new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is, create your own `promise` and put the `ajax` call inside it

Then call `resolve` and pass data that you want when then is called

```
resolve(data_passed_to_then)
```

Like this :

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function (data) {
                let redirectUrl = '/client/' + data
                resolve(redirectUrl);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, err)  {
                ...
                // return dispatch({type: GET_CLIENT_FAIL, err});
                reject(err);
            }
        })
})
```

Comment: works like a miracle. Thank u very much. My first time using Promise :).

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial, Great , Happy coding :)